# css3 box model floating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new bie to web designing I think my understanding problem of box layout.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/XxJqr/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="inner left">....foofoofoo..</p>
  <p class="inner right">....blablabla..</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.content{
   display:-webkit-box;
}
```

Now **my problem is I have to align the inner elements one ot left and the other to right**.

I know how to do it in old way but I would like to do it with box property.

old way to do it.

```
.content{
  display:block;
}
.left{
   float:left;
}

.right{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is here.

Comment: actully not getting your question

Comment: sorry for my poor communication i would like to float the paragraphs without using float property.

Comment: when I use both display:box and flaot:left||right; the elements are not visible.

Comment: Have a look at this article here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/ It talks all about the use of flexbox which I think is what you are looking for. See the middle-to-end of the article for all the positioning/floating examples.

Comment: have you seen the fiddle i would like to get the ".content" box similar to ".content2"

Comment: Also look at this on how to use flexbox, very nice online "app" showing you the CSS dynamically: http://flexiejs.com/playground/ that should get you started, once you found out how to do it with CSS3 please share the answer as I would love to know it myself :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl i didnt found answer in that articles

Comment: @rameshbabu: `..but I would like to do it with box property` I assumed you were refering to the CSS3 box model. The article and the playground I linked show the use of CSS3 box styles and how they are used with tons of examples. If that is not what you were refering to than I don't know what it is you are actualy asking. Apologies if I missunderstood your question and if the links were not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the box-pack property to justify your content.

```
box-pack:justify;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/XxJqr/5/) of working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that works quite nicely:

```
.content{
    display: -webkit-box;
}

.inner {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
```

And doesn't require fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

Opera and IE do not support this and as it's layout based it's probably left alone for corporate site but ok for personal as you would need to style it the normal way anyway.